# Implementing logical negation with only bitwise operators (except !)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, negation

`~ & ^ | + << >>` are the only operations I can use

Before I continue, this is a homework question, I've been stuck on this for a really long time.

My original approach: I thought that !x could be done with two's complement and doing something with it's additive inverse.   I know that an xor is probably in here but I'm really at a loss how to approach this.

For the record: I also cannot use conditionals, loops, `==`, etc, only the functions (bitwise) I mentioned above.

For example:

```
!0 = 1
!1 = 0
!anything besides 0 = 0
```

Comment: Do you really want them to evaluate directly to 1 and 0, or simply logical true and false?  i.e. is `~0` acceptable as logical true?

Comment: Note: `+` is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: This kind of exercise is inherently meaningless because any *use* of the result requires a conditional that's essentially comparison against zero. My answer would be `if (var); else { /* your code here */ }`

Comment: @R.: The trick is that you don't need to use conditionals because C doesn't have `bool`. (E.g. instead of `return x != 0;` you can just say `return x;` assuming that he doesn't need `1` returned... that's what I'm trying to figure out.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: C99 does have `bool`, but AFAIK you have to include `stdbool.h` to get it unless you're happy saying `_Bool`.

Comment: @mu is too short: Haha... *every* time I say "C doesn't have feature X" someone immediately replies that C99 has it. :) I stand corrected, although I never refer to C99 unless I mention it explicitly.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Unary + could be considered bitwise.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming a 32 bit unsigned int:

```
(((x>>1) | (x&1)) + ~0U) >> 31
```

should do the trick

Comment: Nice. Converts all numbers except 0 to "positive", and then subtracts 1, which makes only 0 negative, and then extracts the sign bit.

Comment: This can be simplified to `(~(x >> 1) + x) >> 31`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `x` is signed, need to return 0 for any number not zero, and 1 for zero.

A right shift on a signed integer usually is an arithmetical shift in most implementations (e.g. the sign bit is copied over). Therefore right shift `x` by 31 and its negation by 31. One of those two will be a negative number and so right shifted by 31 will be 0xFFFFFFFF (of course if x = 0 then the right shift will produce 0x0 which is what you want). You don't know if x or its negation is the negative number so just 'or' them together and you will get what you want. Next add 1 and your good.

implementation:

```
int bang(int x) {
    return ((x >> 31) | ((~x + 1) >> 31)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you should negate instead of adding one. Namely, `~((x >> 31) | ((~x + 1) >> 31))`.

Comment: Actually, no. Adding 1 is correct. I forgot that `>>` shifts are arithmetic in C, not logical. Thus, `>> 31`-ing `10...00` will yield `11...11`, not `00...01`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code copies any 1 bit to all positions.  This maps all non-zeroes to `0xFFFFFFFF == -1`, while leaving `0` at `0`.  Then it adds 1, mapping `-1` to `0` and `0` to `1`.

```
x = x | x << 1  | x >> 1
x = x | x << 2  | x >> 2
x = x | x << 4  | x >> 4
x = x | x << 8  | x >> 8
x = x | x << 16 | x >> 16

x = x + 1
```

Comment: Instead of `x + 1` you could do `~x`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: That maps 0 to -1, instead of the required 1.

Answer (score 1):

For 32 bit signed integer x

```
// Set the bottom bit if any bit set.
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
x |= x >> 4;
x |= x >> 8;
x |= x >> 16;

x ^= 1;   // Toggle the bottom bit - now 0 if any bit set.
x &= 1;   // Clear the unwanted bits to leave 0 or 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming e.g. an 8-bit unsigned type:

```
~(((x >> 0) & 1)
| ((x >> 1) & 1) 
| ((x >> 2) & 1)
...
| ((x >> 7) & 1)) & 1
```

Comment: @Jay - Do a cast like `*(unsigned *)&i`

Answer (score -3):

You can just do ~x & 1 because it yields 1 for 0 and 0 for everything else

Comment: ~0x0002 = 0xFFFD, 0xFFFD & 1 = 1